# How to access data stored in server.R from outside the server/UI

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, r-markdown

I am pretty new to R/Rshiny/RMarkdown and I have taken some basic userinput templates to build an app. What I want is for the user to input a filepath and to be able to call the filename and filepath in another function/chunk.

I've come to find that reactive is probably a key function to do this, but I'm not sure quite how to employ it.

```
library(shinyFiles)


  ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                                    title = "Please select a file:", multiple = TRUE,
                          buttonType = "default", class = NULL),

              textOutput("filename"), 
              textOutput("txt_file")
                   )

  filepath <- reactiveValues() #trying, but this isn't quite working
  server <- function(input,output,session){

    volumes = getVolumes()
    observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)

    if(!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
      # browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
      output$filename <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$name))
      filepath <- reactive({output$txt_file}) #an attempt, but it isn't doing what I want.
    }
  })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  isolate(filepath) #also tried print. Really just trying to see if filepath is populated
```

If the user enters /Users/Jim/tmp.txt, I would like to see the UI show /Users/Jim/tmp.txt and tmp.txt (which it does) and also see that /Users/Jim/tmp.txt was stored as the filepath variable that I can access elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `?reactiveValues`. Modified your code and this should work:
**EDIT** Based on your comment, you could try the `system()` command in conjunction with the `glue` package

```
library(shinyFiles)
library(glue)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = TRUE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),

  textOutput("filename"), 
  textOutput("txt_file")
)

rvs <- reactiveValues() #renamed to rvs
server <- function(input,output,session){

  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)

    req(input$Btn_GetFile)

    file_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
    output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
    output$filename <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$name))
    rvs$filepath <- as.character(file_selected$datapath)
    print(rvs$filepath) #Added this print to test

  })
}
observe({
  req(rvs$filepath)
  system(glue("echo {rvs$filepath}"))
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How would I call rvs$filepath from within a bash chunk? I'm not understanding the concept of a reactive context.
Sys.setenv(file = rvs$filepath) didn't work with 
```{bash}
echo $file
```

Comment: Why would you want it in a bash chunk? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to call an external program to act on an interactive fileinput. So, if I can use shiny to get the input file and pass that to the bash chunk where I can call the program, I would be happy.
```{bash}
binary.bin rvs$fileinput -a parameter1 -b parameter2 > output.file
```


Would it be easier to call an external program from within R, like python's os.system()?

Comment: Have edited my answer. You could try the `system()` function. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Glad it helped!